# A custom background for a modal VC and rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller

I've implemented a custom (blurred) background for a modal view controller on iPad. Here's how I do it: in the presented VC's `viewWillShow:` I take a snapshot image of the presenting VC's view, blur it, and add a UIImage view on top of the presenting VC. This works well.

However, when I rotate the device while the modal is showing, the blurred image gets out of sync with the view controller it represents. The image gets stretched to fill the screen, but the view controller doesn't resize its views the same way. So when the modal is dismissed and the blur goes away, the transition looks bad.

I've tried taking another snapshot in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`, and replacing the blurred image, but that didn't work.

Any advice on how to solve this?

UPDATE: [a sample project](http://stashbox.org/1445183/ModalTest.zip)

**My code (in the modal view controller):**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self drawBackgroundBlurView];
}    

- (void)drawBackgroundBlurView
{
    if(_blurModalBackground) {

        [_backgroundBlurView removeFromSuperview];

        CGRect backgroundFrame = self.presentingViewController.view.bounds;

        _backgroundBlurView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:backgroundFrame];
        _backgroundBlurView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

        [_backgroundBlurView setImage:[STSUtils imageByBlurringView:self.presentingViewController.view]];

        [self.presentingViewController.view addSubview:_backgroundBlurView];
    }
}
```

**Utils code**

```
+ (UIImage *)imageByBlurringView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject];

    BOOL isPortrait = (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]));

    CGRect frame;
    if(isPortrait) {
        frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.height, view.frame.size.width);
    }
    else {
        frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, NO, window.screen.scale);

    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:frame afterScreenUpdates:NO];

    // Get the snapshot
    UIImage *snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // Apply blur
    UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.3];
    UIImage *blurredSnapshotImage = [snapshotImage applyBlurWithRadius:8
                                                             tintColor:tintColor
                                                 saturationDeltaFactor:1.8
                                                             maskImage:nil];

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return blurredSnapshotImage;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the actual code.

Comment: @MaxK posted the code.

Comment: Why do you add subview to `self.presentingViewController`? If I understand right you want to show blurred image of `presentingViewController` in your modal one - then you should do `[self.view addSubView:_backgroundBlurView]`

Comment: @MaxK I just want to change the default appearance of a modal (non-fullscreen) view on an iPad. The default behavior is to make the background semi-transparent. I add a blur to that. The modal view controller is not affected. The blur image needs to go beneath the modal, so I add it to the presenting VC. I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Could you please save the image into photos with the following code `UIImage *img = [STSUtils imageByBlurringView:self.presentingViewController.view];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, NULL);` and post it here. We need to localize an error - whether it screenshoted or displayed incorrectly. Try both orientaitons with and without presented modal controller.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please add yo your question a relevant code. At least `imageByBlurringView` method. It may save the time to anyone who look at your question later. Downloading a project may be inconvenient. Thank you.

Comment: @MaxK, thanks! That is the best solution I've seen so far. I'm going to accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I coded a simple example that takes a screenshot from `presentingViewController` and sets it as background image. Here is the implementaion of my modal view controller. And it works well (both on `viewWillAppear` and handles rotation properly). Could you please also post `STSUtils` code?

```
#import "ScreenshoterViewController.h"

@interface ScreenshoterViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

- (IBAction)buttonBackPressed;

@end

@implementation ScreenshoterViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self updateImage];
}

- (void)updateImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.presentingViewController.view.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.imageView.image = img;
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [self updateImage];
}

- (IBAction)buttonBackPressed {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                             completion:NULL];
}
@end
```

**Update**

In your utils code just replace this

```
[view drawViewHierarchyInRect:frame afterScreenUpdates:NO];
```

with this

```
[view drawViewHierarchyInRect:frame afterScreenUpdates:YES];
```

From apple docs:

> afterUpdates A Boolean value that indicates whether the snapshot
>   should be rendered after recent changes have been incorporated.
>   Specify the value NO if you want to render a snapshot in the view
>   hierarchy’s current state, which might not include recent changes.

So you were taking screenshot that did not included latest changes in the view.

Comment: I think you're answering a slightly different question here :) I'm not looking to snapshot the presenter VC and show it in the modal VC. I'm looking to overlay the presenter VC with its own snapshot image, but blurred. I'll try to draw a diagram and add it to my question.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get what you want for the first time. But now I do, will try to help you.

Comment: I've posted a sample project illustrating the problem. Try (1) opening the modal, then (2) rotating the screen, and (3) then closing the  modal. You'll see that the blurred background in (2) doesn't match the actual background in (3).

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer?
Is there a sample project that shows the re-drawing work?

Comment: I would replace didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation with viewWillLayoutSubviews - works better, but still rotation is not handled at the best way.